# Relink objects from most basic Qt application - Linker error

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ld

Try first if the simple demo app (the console project template) compiles with qmake command line:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin;C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\Tools\mingw530_32\bin
C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe -makefile C:\Software\test.pro -spec win32-g++
mingw32-make.exe
pause
```

Now trying to relink the application:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\ld -o test release\main.o -LC:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin -lQt5Core --verbose > ld_dump.txt
pause
```

Errors

```
main.o undefined reference to _Unwind_Resume
main.o undefined reference to __gxx_personality_v0
```

For comparison a slightly more complex app with QtWidgets prodcues even more errors (of course I added the missing Qt libs in the linker bat file)

```
moc_widget.o undefined reference to strcmp
moc_widget.o QObject undefined reference to vtable for __xyyabiv1:: __class_type_info
...
```

Googling error 1+2 they say it may be caused by different compilers. But I am using the same tool.

The pro file looks like

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = test
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Do I maybe need to pass some kind of c++11 flag to the linker `ld`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ld needs a lot more information (e.g. it doesn't know anything about stdc++). Why don't you link using g++, instead? A line like this should work:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\g++.exe \
-Wl,-rpath,C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin \
-o test release\main.o -LC:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin -lQt5Core
```

Comment: This works: `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin;C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\Tools\mingw530_32\bin
C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\g++.exe -Wl,-rpath,C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin -o test  release\main.o -LC:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin -lQt5Core` I did not know I could use g++ only for linking. I thought it would be nonsense to call g++ again after it was called by mingw32-make. The point that `ld` needs a lot more information: I kind of asked this at the end of my question. The manpage at `https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld` did not help me to run it just with `ld`

Comment: This is the minimal running command that I've found: `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\Tools\mingw530_32\bin
g++ -o test release\main.o -LC:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin -lQt5Core`

Comment: g++ will call ld (or collect2, which is basically the same). You can run g++ with the -v option to see how.